# Mostrar el valor máximo de mi id en sql server y mostrarlo en un jtextfield en netbeans

Tags: sql

Buenas tarde a todos quiero que me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema:

Tengo una bd en sql server en donde tengo una tabla que se llama trabajos y tengo varios registros, tengo un formulario en java netbeans y lo que quiero es que al cargar dicho formulario en un jtextfield se muestre el último valor del registro que hay en el campo id de la tabla mencionada, y se la pueda sumar 1 ya que lo que pretendo es que el usuario vea el código que se le asignara a su registro cuando lo guarde.

Les dejo parte de mi código:

```
void UltIdTraSoli(){

        try {

            Statement sen1 = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2 = sen1.executeQuery("select idtrabajo from trabajos");
            rs2.last();
            String result = rs2.getString("idtrabajo");

            txtCodigo.setText(String.valueOf(rs2.getInt(result)));

        } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }      
    }
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Karlitos, podrias usar el Max() de Sql, para obtener el valor mas grande de tu id por ejemplo select max(idtrabajo) from trabajos, por que de la manera en que haces el query, te va a traer todos los idtrabajo que tenga tu tabla.

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, lo tenía de esa manera en un procedimiento almacenado pero ya estando en java me dio problemas para mostrarlo en jtextfield en netbeans.  No se si me podría dar algun ejemplo.

Comment: Que clase de problema te dio?, el problema que se me viene a la mente, es que el sql cuando usas el MAX(), te devuelve la columna pero sin nombre, así que tu necesitas asignarle un alias, para poder cacharlo en tu código. Ejemplo: select max(idtrabajo) as 'idtrabajo' from trabajos

Comment: ya capturo en System.out.println(resul) el dato pero a la hora de quererlo pasar a mi jtxtfield me dice El nombre de columna 9 no es valido.  ya le asigne un alias como tu me indicas pero me sale el mensaje antes mencionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya solucione el problema con lo que me comentaste de utilizar el MAX(idtrabajo) from trabajo. dejo el codigo por si les sirve.                                                                                                          
 void UltIdTrasoli(){
 try {
 Statement sen1 = cn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs2 = sen1.executeQuery("select MAX(idtrabajo) as codigo from trabajos");
while(rs2.next()){
String resul = rs2.getString(1);
txtCodigo.setText(resul);}
catch (Exception e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}}

Comment: Me alegro poder haber sido de ayuda, saludos Karlitos.